# How to draw directly to memory using a pointer to the bitmap data in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, bitmap, mfc, drawing

The problem I face is the fact that it is not possible to draw to one hdc from multiple threads simultaneously. I have found out that it is possible to create a bitmap, lock it for the write access and get the pointer to the bitmap data in memory. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598872/creating-hbitmap-from-memory-buffer) thread is about this topic, however I struggle with implementing all this.

My first question is: if I want to get this pointer to the data, does it matter how the bitmap was created (CreateCimpatibleDC() or CreateDIBitmap())?

The second question is: how to get that pointer? In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588132/is-it-possible-to-bitblt-directly-from-a-gdi-bitmap) thread it is received from the CreateDIBSection() function.

Could anyone provide me with the tiny example how to access the data using the pointer please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937095/creating-a-hbitmap-from-an-existing-buffer/21941601#21941601) might help you

Comment: Thank you for the link. However I struggle with the "data" variable. Which type should it be so that I could draw a pixel on the bitmap?
Another question: if I "talk" directly with memory, I probably don't need to run BeginPaint and EndPaint, right?

Comment: You create an *hBitmap* in memory but your drawings involve *dc's*. It is the way GDI works. You can't draw an *hBitmap*, only *dc's*. This *hdc* is what you *bitblt()* into the *hdc* you get from *BeginPaint*. So you need it. You can't get a pointer from the control *hdc* unfortunatelly.

Comment: *...I struggle with the "data" variable*. If the *hBitmap* is 24bit, to set a pixel color eg the first one(blue): `data[0] = 255; data[1] = 0; data[2] = 0'. The colors are BGR BGR ... I am not sure however if the first pixel in *data* array is the *top-left* or *bottom-right* of the bitmap. You need to experiment a little.